# convert string into Quantlib Date()

Tags: python, quantlib

I am reading some parameters data from a csv and I am struggling to convert the date so that it is accepted by the class Date()

I have tried that:

```
d = datetime.date(datetime.strptime('2011-03-07','%Y-%m-%d'))
Date(d)
```

but it returns:

> NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded
>   function 'new_Date'.

Comment: What is `Date`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: Quantlib Date()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QuantLib provides a `DateParser` class that does the job without passing through `datetime`; you can write

```
d = DateParser.parseFormatted('2011-03-07','%Y-%m-%d')
```

to get your `Date` instance.  This also works in C++, where you would write

```
Date d = DateParser::parseFormatted('2011-03-07','%Y-%m-%d')
```

or in other languages towards which QuantLib is exported through SWIG.

Comment: If you already have a `datetime` instance, instead, merlin2011's answer is of course the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

The [quantlib documentation](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_date.html) suggests that you should be passing in the following arguments, rather than a Python `datetime`.

```
Date (Day d, Month m, Year y)
```

There does not appear to be Python API documentation at the moment, but according to [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/19077), it matches the C++, then it should work to simply pass in integers for each value. That is, you would pass in the following arguments for March 3, 2011.

```
Date(3, 3, 2011)
```

To convert from the string, you could either manually parse the string, or use the datetime class as you have done.

```
d = datetime.strptime('2011-03-07','%Y-%m-%d')
quantDate = Date(d.day, d.month, d.year)
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into using the `dateutil` module.

```
from dateutil import parser

parser.parse('2011-03-07')
# datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 7, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect.

Change this line:
    `d = datetime.date(datetime.strptime('2011-03-07','%Y-%m-%d'))`

to this:
    `datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d')`

It's a minor change but should help.